# regex pattern starting with "=" and exceptions

Tags: json, regex, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write an expression which will be used with json files for a vscode extension. My expression should start with `"=\s*"` and then I want it to select everything after the equal except for the following cases:

1. `TRUE` or `FALSE` after the equality
2. starting with digit
3. starting with ' or "

I have tried many things and separately each case I manage to make it work but when I try to put it all together, it doesn't work

Example of doc strings:

> abc = test
> abc = TRUE
> abc = FALSE
> abc = "test"
> abc = 'test'
> abc = 123

Out of these examples my regex should only keep the very first one and "test" can be anything.

What was the closest to the solution was this one `/(=\s*)^(((?!TRUE|FALSE|[0-9]|\"|\').)*)$/gm`

Comment: Please add what you tried to the question. What was the exact problem with "joining" the patterns? Have you got any test cases/text you tested against? Please also add it here and state the expected behavior.

Comment: perhaps even add test cases such as "abc" should match but "abd" should not match

Comment: Maybe you are just trying to read something like a [dotenv](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv) file and you should probably go for an [already existing solution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

Comment: Sorry, do you want to match the whole line or just `=` and whitespace?  If the latter use `=(?!\s*(?:TRUE|FALSE|[0-9"']))\s*`, else, use `.*=(?!\s*(?:TRUE|FALSE|[0-9"'])).*`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "keep the very first line", or let know if any of the above suggestions worked for you.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear from the first line I want to keep `= test`

Comment: Try `^(.*?=)(?!\s*(?:TRUE|FALSE|[0-9"'])).*` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: It sounds like you're planning to parse JSON using regular expressions. If so, it's not the tool to use, and you're going to run into problems when you get JSON that doesn't look exactly like you're expecting it.

Comment: What do you mean by `3. starting with "or "`?  Your regex doesn't mention it so you need to give a better example of that test case.

Comment: As @AndyLester says, in an extension you should be able to parse the file as JSON and handle it from there.  You should post what your json file actually looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

**Find what**: `^(.*?=)(?!\s*(?:TRUE|FALSE|[0-9"'])).*`
**Replace With**: `$1`

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(.*?=)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible and then a `=` char
- `(?!\s*(?:TRUE|FALSE|[0-9"']))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
  - `(?:TRUE|FALSE|[0-9"'])` - `TRUE`, `FALSE`, digit or `"` or `'`
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tmKVXb/1) and the demo screenshot:

[image]