# JSON SERVER - how to pass filter to json to get only those array items that start with the respective letters passed in the filter

Tags: json, api, rest, http, backend

I am using json server to simulate an API and wanted to know how to pass the filter to json to get only the array items that start with the respective letters passed in the filter

I passed this to my get

http://localhost:3000/produtos?name_like=a

```
[
    {
        "name": "amora",
        "birth": "12.12.2000",
        "city": "teste",
        "phone": "(21) 21",
        "id": 12
    },
    {
        "name": "angola",
        "birth": "12.12.2000",
        "city": "teste",
        "phone": "(21) 21",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "germany",
        "birth": "12.12.2000",
        "city": "teste",
        "phone": "(21) 21",
        "id": 52
    }
]
```

but it returned all the items in the array that have the letter A in their name, but I want it to return only those that start with the letter A

Answer (score 0):

Based on [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server), `_like` works as a filter support **`[RegExp][2]`**.

So, in your case (start the letter "a").

```
http://localhost:3000/produtos?name_like=^(a).*
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(a)` - group of one letter *a*
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

You can check also another [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68065025/regex-pattern-starting-with-and-exceptions/68070420#68070420) in stackoverflow.